# How to get Google access token in the background of web application without user's interfering

Tags: rest, google-oauth, access-token

I have a web application where I'm using Google API services which require an **access-token**. 
All I want is a background process to get an access token and execute request without user's interfering.

I have tried various ways to get an access token (Google SDK Shell, Google Platform, Exchange auth code for access token).
When I'm working with Postman I have no problem with that but in my web application I don't want to redirect the user to the Google login for authorization to get the code and then request the access token. I don't want the authorization to be visible at all for my user.

Comment: Think that I have only one user (admin) who has a service account with credentials, API key, etc saved in a file. Every other user of the webapp can see results of the Google services but in the background I use only admin's access token and credentials. All I want is the authorization to complete with my admin account every time we use a service and not with a simple user's authorization who has not a google account. Is it possible?

Comment: I explained my situation better if I was not clear enough. Your comment is was fine. Thanks

Comment: If you do not need the users to provide the Access Token, use a Service Account in your backend code. I will assume that you have implemented some form of authentication with your users. There are lots of examples on the Internet. Just search "Google Cloud Service Account Examples". My person blog has about a dozen articles on service accounts: https://jhanley.com

Comment: I have created a service account for my project but I don't know how to get a refresh token. Is there an endpoint to make a request and get it ? Because I read some articles from your blog I tried also the JWT way but I got Invalid JWT Signature (I'm using Java)

Comment: Service Accounts do use Refresh Tokens but that is hidden from you. You should track the expiration time and create a new token. Tokens are good for 3600 seconds. There are examples in Java on the Internet. Using a service account is very easy and is the standard method with Google.